# Why does this DELETE query fail when the equivalent SELECT works?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have two tables, products(product_id) and sex(product_id,sex_id). I am trying to DELETE rows from both tables that have a product_id such that there exists a row in the sex table with this product_id and sex=1. So far I have

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempTable
      SELECT p.product_id  
        FROM products AS p
  INNER JOIN sex AS s
          ON p.product_id = s.product_id 
       WHERE s.sex = 1;

 DELETE FROM products AS p
NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t
```

The DELETE query throws this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t' at line 2
```

This SELECT query works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM products
NATURAL JOIN tempTable
```

Why does the SELECT query work, but the DELETE query does not?

Comment: I'm no mysql expert, but your `AS p` and `AS t` aliases don't seem to make sense in a `DELETE` query. Does it work if you remove them?

Comment: @JoeWhite Why shouldn't they make sense? You can use them in the `WHERE` if you have one. Or (see my answer) to specify in which of the tables the `DELETE` should occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `DELETE` has a [different syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html). You have to specify from which table(s) you want to delete.

So do one of

```
DELETE p, t FROM products AS p NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t;
DELETE p FROM products AS p NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t;
DELETE t FROM products AS p NATURAL JOIN tempTable AS t;
```